Ошибка маршрутизации после обновления WordPress Elementor PRO
После того, как обновил Элементор до Про версии сломалась маршрутизация: когда перехожу на любую страницу в любой http-запрос добавляется лишняя приставка "https://" из-за которой невозможен переход на страницу. Как это можно пофиксить?

Что значит "добавляется лишняя приставка "https://"? Адрес как выглядит? И показывай пациента.

Выглядит так: https://https://fiendmagic.ru/"имя раздела и статьи"
